# Can I say the functional is bounded?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functions

Let $A\subset X$ be a closed linear subspace, and $x_{0}\in X$.

I know that for any $x\in A_{1}=span(A,x_{0})$, $x=y+ax_{0}$ with unique $y\in A$ and $a\in \Bbb R$(or $\Bbb C$).

If I define a functional $f$ on $A_{1}$ such that $f(x)=a$, is $f$ bounded? And if it is, can I say $f$ is bounded because for any given $x\in A_{1}$, $f(x)\le|a|$?
I doubt that because I think I need to find a universal bound for $f$, but I'm not sure how I can do that since $\Bbb R$(or $\Bbb C$) is unbounded.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your functional $f$ is bounded on $A_1$. To show that it is bounded, you must find some $C \geq 0$ such that
$|f(x)| \leq C || x ||$
for all $x \in A_1$.

In your example, $|f(x)| = |a |$, so we should try to relate $|a|$ to $||x||$.

To do this, define $d$ to be the shortest distance from $x_0$ to the subspace $A$,
$$d = {\rm dist}(x_0,A) = \inf_{y \in A} || x_0 - y ||.$$

We have
$$ || x|| = || y+ ax_0 || = |a| \times || (1/a)y + x_0 || \geq |a| \times d ,$$
so $|a| \leq (1/d) \times || x || $.

Thus $|f(x)| \leq C ||x||$ for all $x \in A_1$ with $C = |a|/d$.